# RxJS BehaviorSubject with custom create logic

Tags: rxjs

Because `BehaviorSubject` extends `Subject` and `Subject` extends `Observable`, all of those three have static `.create(observer)` method to create them using custom values emission logic.
I' able to use with good result `Observable.create(observer)`, for instance:

```
a = Rx.Observable.create(obs => {
    setInterval(() => {
        obs.next('tick');
    }, 500)
})
s = a.subscribe(v => console.log(v))
```

Gives me expected output (`tick` every 500ms)

But when I replace `Observable` with `Subject`/`BehaviorSubject`, it's not so willing to get up and running:

```
a = Rx.Subject.create(obs => {
    setInterval(() => {
        obs.next('tick');
    }, 500)
})
s = a.subscribe(v => console.log(v)); // Nothing
a.next(5); // Still nothing
```

Basically, subject seems to work as intended to only if they are created via `new` operator like below:

```
a = new Rx.Subject();
s = a.subscribe(v => {console.log(v)});
a.next(5) // Ok, got value here
```

Even if I try to use non-parametrized create method, which invocation shall boil down to same result as using new:

```
a = Rx.Subject.create();
```

I'm still unable to force it to emit values.

I'm aware that subjects are designed to receive values from outside world (not to generate them internally as Observables), thus subject shall be triggered by external code with `subject.next('value')`, but I was just curios that if they are strictly related to Observables, logic behind `create` and further behavior shall be same...

Can anyone explain, why usage of `create` on `Subject` (even if they are not designed to work this way, but still it shall be possible) does not work as supposed to?

Comment: I think you need to pass observable arg also to create function.  Because subscribe method of AnonymousSubject(whic is called when you use create function) expects it. See the below code `_subscribe(subscriber: Subscriber<T>): Subscription {
    const { source } = this;
    if (source) {
      return this.source.subscribe(subscriber);
    } else {
      return Subscription.EMPTY; 
    }
  }`  for more info [https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subject.ts]